# Is there a way for URL to be only accessed through the same origin

Tags: django

I have a URL in my Django application.

```
url(r'^settings/$', views.SettingsView.as_view(), name='settings')
```

This url is just a `TemplateView` that shows an HTML page. I don't want this page accessed to the public. Is there a way for only the application can access it? For example, the application can call this URL and retrieve data, but any outside user can't. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What does "only the application" mean? You can restrict views to users that have particular permission including system accounts that applications use

Comment: For example, if a user tries to query an API endpoint, it maybe restricted to them because they're coming from an external domain. However, the web application itself (website) can query that endpoint because it belongs to the same origin as the hosted API.

Comment: You mean that you want to implement CORS?

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I want

Comment: Have a look at this package https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Comment: Thanks that should help!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in views.py.
Check origin in your function like this:

```
if request.META['HTTP_ORIGIN'] == "domain":
    do somthing
else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Not a really good solution, i believe. Using `CORS` is more suitable.